# Запятая, тире после пояснительного оборота

Tags: тире

> Письмо, направленное в адрес ведомства, зарегистрированное в системе,
> - рассмотрено в соответствии с утверждёнными правилами.

Уместно ли применение тире после запятой?

Answer (score 2):

Здесь тире по стилю не подходит. Для делового стиля не характерно употребление интонационного тире, там нет места эмоциям.

Но требуется правка, потому что в "*направленное в адрес ведомства, зарегистрированное в системе*" нет однородности, оно не звучит рядом. Так лучше:
*Зарегистрированное в системе письмо, направленное в адрес ведомства, рассмотрено в соответствии с утверждёнными правилами.*